# Getting Value from Firebase Real-time Database (Qt c++)

Tags: android, c++, firebase, qt, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Qt to develop an application for Android, at this moment I am trying to get a value from my Firebase real-time database but I keep getting **0** (**false**) for `firebase::kFutureStatusPending`. I am able to set value by using `SetValue()` on my database and I have checked the `url` with  `dbref.Child(user->uid()).Child("Nickname").url()` and it is correct. here is a piece of my code related to this part and I also have included JSON structure at the end:

```
firebase::database::Database *database=firebase::database::Database::GetInstance(_app);
dbref = database->GetReferenceFromUrl("https://***/");

firebase::Future<firebase::database::DataSnapshot> result =
    dbref.Child(user->uid()).Child("Nickname").GetValue();


if (result.status() != firebase::kFutureStatusPending) {
  if (result.status() != firebase::kFutureStatusComplete) {
    qDebug() <<"ERROR: GetValue() returned an invalid result.";

  } else if (result.error() != firebase::database::kErrorNone) {
    qDebug() << result.error_message();

  } else {
    firebase::database::DataSnapshot snapshot = *result.result();
    qDebug() << "snapshot available" ;
  }
}

else {
    qDebug() << "results are still pending";
}
```

How can I get the value of `Nickname` child (which is `Raad` in this case) in my `Qt Android app`?

Here is the `JSON` file content :

```
{
  "YQEa5KquWgOiPHfD7SLSgU92mTH2" : {
    "Email Address" : "shariatraad@gmail.com",
    "Nickname" : "Raad"
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: And I should also mention that by using `user->uid()` I get the UID of user which is **YQEa5KquWgOiPHfD7SLSgU92mTH2** in this case

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the question and included the JSON file content.

Comment: As I check again my exact problem is that `firebase::kFutureStatusPending` tells me my results are still pending. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In copying the code from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data), you've missed this comment it seems:

```
// In the game loop that polls for the result...

if (result.status() != firebase::kFutureStatusPending) {
  if (result.status() != firebase::kFutureStatusComplete) {
```

Since the data is loaded asynchronously, the `result.status()` won't be complete right way. For that reason you need to have this check in your game loop, or in some other place that runs repeatedly.

Alternatively, you can use `Future.onCompletion` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/future.html#classfirebase_1_1_future):

> ```
> // Or, set an OnCompletion callback, which accepts a C++11 lambda or
> // function pointer. You can pass your own user data to the callback. In
> // most cases, the callback will be running in a different thread, so take
> // care to make sure your code is thread-safe.
> future.OnCompletion([](const Future< SampleResultType >& completed_future,
>                        void* user_data) {
>   // We are probably in a different thread right now.
>   if (completed_future.error() == 0) {
>     DoSomethingWithResultData(completed_future.result());
>   }
>   else {
>     LogMessage("Error %d: %s",
>                completed_future.error(),
>                completed_future.error_message());
>   }
> }, user_data);
> ```

But in this case too, it's important to make sure (the `main` of) your program doesn't exit before the data is retrieved, or you'll never see it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.What do you exactly mean by running it my code repeatedly?